# Pine script for price box

Tags: pine-script

I would like to draw a price box. So we get two price level. Now I want to calculate some percentage from any one level and draw a horizontal line within that box.

Ex: Price box starting at 100 and ending at 70. Hence 30% price drop. Horizontal line at 10% (90) price drop from top (100).

Is it possible in trading view pine script?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code of what you have tried so far.
This forum can provide suggestions to your attempted code, but avoids writing full fledged code for your requirements.